# in bash - how to get the last element in line

Tags: bash, while-loop

input : 1 -> 2

```
while read -a line; do

  if (( line[2] < 1 )); then
    echo "Graph does not match known sites3"
    exit
  fi

done < "$2"
```

Error

```
syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "")
```

For some reason line[2] is not treated as the number 2...
how can i solve this?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Could you make the exact input clearer?

Comment: turn on shell debugging to see the processing of your conditions, i.e. `set -vx`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

To get the last array element :

```
$ x=( a z e r t y)
$ echo ${x[-1]}
y
```

Comment: Hey....I think that would work..but i have another problem that's preventing me from getting an answer for this correction ur suggested...

Comment: input : 4  a.bcd

i was the program to realize it's an illegal line..cause there's 2 spaces between
the first number and the string.....
only 1 space is considered legal
now...my problem is that when i use: `echo "$line" | cut -d" " -f2` 
ignores the two spaces and treat them as one...

what to do ?


while read line; do

webName=`echo "$line" | cut -d" " -f2`
  if [[ "$webName" =~ ^[A-Za-z0-9.]*$ ]]; then
 continue;
 else 
 echo "Illegal sites list"
 exit
  fi